# Using the amsbook Class

Tags: amsbook

I am trying to figure out how to tweak various stylistic aspects of the amsbook class. For example, I would like for the chapter and section headers to be left-aligned instead of centered. Also, using the plain theorem style, I would like for the words "theorem", "proof" etc. to be bold. I would also like to figure out how to make theorems not be indented. So, are there simple ways of accomplishing these things or would I be better off basing a custom book class based on the amsbook class? Are there other book classes available that would perhaps be easier to style than the amsbook class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several questions here.

1. You can define a new page style to change the header format. In my example code this is done defining `\ps@spheadings`.
2. You can define a new theorem style to change the format for the theorem-like structures. In my example code this is done defining `\th@spplain`.I defined this new style using low-level commands, but you could use the features provided by the [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package.

   ```
   \documentclass{amsbook}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \makeatletter
   \def\ps@spheadings{\ps@empty
     \def\@evenhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
         \rlap{\thepage}\hfil \leftmark{}{}}%
     \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
         \rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}}%
     \let\@mkboth\markboth
     \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
     \def\chaptermark{%
       \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
     \def\sectionmark{%
       \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
   }
   \def\th@spplain{%
     \let\thm@indent\relax
     \thm@headfont{\bfseries}% heading font bold face
     \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
     \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                       \@minus.2\baselineskip
     \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
     \normalfont
   }
   \makeatother

   \theoremstyle{spplain}
   \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

   \pagestyle{spheadings}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{A test chapter}
   \section{A test section}
   \begin{theo}
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{theo}
   \lipsum[1-30]

   \end{document}
   ```

Although both modifications are not difficult to achieve, you should think carefully if `amsbook` is really the best class for you, or if perhaps some other class would suit you better.

To customize the theorem-like structures, you can use the `amsthm` package (I already provided the link); the [ntheorem](http://www.cta.org/pkg/ntheorem) package could also be a possibility if your document class is not from the AMS collection.

If you decide not to use the `amsbook` document class, but to use some of the standard document classes, then you can customize the headers using either the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) packages.

In [What are the available “documentclass” types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/3954) you can find a description of some of the available document classes; besides `amsbook`, and `book`, the document classes `scrbook` and `memoir` could be an option for you.

Here's a simple schematic document showing `titlesec` and `amsthm` in action with the `book` document class:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
 \sethead[left-odd][center-odd][right-odd]{left-even}{center-even}{right-odd}
  \setfoot[left-odd][center-odd][right-odd]{left-even}{center-even}{right-odd}
}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{3pt}% ⟨Space above⟩
{3pt}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\normalfont}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theo}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. Although of course I can copy your code, this seems neither easy nor simple. I would certainly be open to using another book class; do you have a suggestion?

Comment: OK, that definitely works but now the theorem text is back to being italicized (which I don't want). I certainly *hope* there's a document class that's easier to configure...

Comment: @3Sphere: see my updated answer.

Comment: `\theoremstyle{definition}` is identical to the default `\theoremstyle{plain}` in every way except that the body font is not italic.  so if that is the only reason to want to change the style, there's no need to define a new one.  (and `\theoremstyle{remark}` is like `definition` without the extra space above and below.)

Answer (score 5):

You can change the style and indentation of the theorems using the `amsthm` package, which is loaded automatically when you use `amsbook`. Use

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% ⟨name⟩
{3pt}% ⟨Space above⟩
{3pt}% ⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}% ⟨Body font⟩
{}% ⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bf}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}% ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}% ⟨Space after theorem head⟩
{}% ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩

\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
```

You can also change the proof; see
[Changing style of Proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8089/changing-style-of-proof).

If you would like a recommendation for a book class, I'd say use `scrbook` (part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) bundle). You'll need to load any AMS classes you want to use, but KOMA-Script makes it really easy to customize book layout using commands. It has the added benefit (to you) of left-aligning chapters and section by default.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the various stylistic aspects of `amsbook` class, the following code worked well for me to adjust Caption and the Section heading styles. I just pasted it into the preamble of my LyX document.

The `caption` package seems to work with `amsbook` class. But, `sectsty` package will not work with `amsbook`.

```
\usepackage[format=plain,labelsep=period,justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf, margin=10pt]{caption}

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%              % the name
{1}%                    % the level
{0mm}%                  % the indent
{-0.5\baselineskip}%    % the before skip
{0.25\baselineskip}%    % the after skip
{\normalfont\large\bf}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
{subsection}%                % the name
{2}%                         % the level
{0mm}%                       % the indent
{0mm}%                       % the before skip
{0.1mm}%                     % the after skip
{\normalfont\normalsize\bf}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection
{subsubsection}%                % the name
{3}%                            % the level
{0mm}%                          % the indent
{0mm}%                          % the before skip
{0.1mm}%                        % the after skip
{\normalfont\normalsize\bf\it}} % the style
```