# How do I change the header of table of contents with amsbook style file?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, amsbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the amsbook Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35215/using-the-amsbook-class)

I am trying to change the header in the table of contents page with `amsbook` style file.

I tried:

```
\makepagestyle{calification}
\makeheadrule{calification}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{calification}{\uppercase{new header}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{calification}{\uppercase{new header}}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{calification}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{calification}{}{}{}

\def\calification{
\newpage
\null\vfil
\clearpage
\pagestyle{calification}
}
\def\endcalification{\par\vfil\newpage}
```

And then use

```
\begin{calification}
\tableofcontents
\end{calification}
```

This does not work with `amsbook` -- for some reason it tells me that `\makepagestyle` is an undefined sequence:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 l.46 \makepagestyle
               {calification}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using the `fancyhdr` package? It shouldn't be hard to incorporate your pagestyle specifications in the `fancy` page style.

Comment: thanks @Mico, it is exactly what I needed. works just great.

Comment: @Mico Can you turn (and expand) your comment into an answer?

Comment: @egreg -- Sorry, I didn't read your comment/suggestion in time before the question was closed as "duplicate".