# Using ntheorem with amsbook

Tags: theorems, document-classes, amsthm, ntheorem, amsbook

I'm working with an `amsbook` document, and I want to use the `ntheorem` package. This is unsurprisingly causing a complaint with the `amsthm` package implicitly loaded for the `amsbook` documentclass. [There's no clear superior choice between `amsthm` and `ntheorem`, each has its plusses and minuses.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5633/109698) So it seemed the best option to use

```
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
```

which gives an approximation of [the best of both worlds](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) (section 3.2.2). But that only works if you can remove the `amsthm` package. How do I achieve this result with the `amsbook` document class?

This code below exhibits alternately a minimal working and broken example:

```
\documentclass{article}%{amsbook}
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

[One answer provided implicitly here was that they just don't blend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35219/109698) but I want to believe that it can be done.

EDIT: @david-carlisle and @barbara-beeton [correct my misapprehension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499530/109698); apparently it is not the `amsthm` package included in `amsbook`, but instead that the `amsbook` class contains code equivalent to that provided in the `amsthm` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normally not too hard to prevent a package loading (if necessary by abusing the mechanism latex uses to prevent a package being loaded twice). However `amsbook` does not load `amsthml` it has the definition of a theorem mechanism inline within the body of `amsbook.cls`. The `amsthm.sty` package is an extraction of a subset of the `amsbook` code for use in non-AMS classes.

As such, it would be simpler to start from a different class and add any AMS-features that you want rather than start from `amsbook` and remove the theorem handling.

Comment: Not only is the code equivalent to that of `amsthm` incorporated into `amsbook`, it's not identical to the standalone `amsthm`.  All AMS document classes *and* `amsthm` are generated from `amsclass.dtx`, so the differences can be determined there.  (All in TeX Live.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree that `ntheorem` is better than `amsthm`.

However, a not thoroughly tested way to remove `amsthm` from `amsbook` is as follows.

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\latex@newtheorem\newtheorem
\let\latex@thm\@thm
\let\latex@xthm\@xthm
\let\latex@ythm\@ythm
\makeatother

\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\let\newtheorem\latex@newtheorem
\let\@thm\latex@thm
\let\@xthm\latex@xthm
\let\@ythm\latex@ythm
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\th@plain\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proofname\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Truly, I don't know enough to have an opinion on which, if either, is better. The other linked post suggested instead it's a function of trade-offs. Thank you for the suggestion.