# Inconsistent "vertical" spacing occurring throughout whole document with disappearing QED symbol

Tags: spacing, proof-package

I am typesetting class notes in TeXstudio for myself. Although I have typeset formulas before using LaTeX code, it's my first time putting a whole LaTeX document together, so I suppose some of the errors might be due to my preamble? Also, I'm pretty sure I don't need most of the packages for the example shown below, but I think I need them for my whole document.

**1)** My main problem is that the spacing between similar "code" is not consistent. For example, the spacing between my theorems and proofs are not the same everywhere. Also, the two parts where I wrote "... of the equation yields:"; the spacing between that text and the `\[ \]` are not the same in both cases.

(I know the proofs are incomplete and have repetitive lines, but I just cut most of it out to avoid having too much text for this question.)

**2)** My other problem is when I add `\renewenvironment{proof}{\textit{\textbf {Proof:}}}` to the preamble to modify the "Proof" text to bold and italics, all my QED blacksquare symbols no longer show up.

My code is:
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.65in, right=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{boiboites}
\usepackage{xkeyval}


\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand*{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=blue, background=blue!5, titlebackground=blue,
titleboxcolor = black]{theo}{Theorem}{subsection}

%\renewenvironment{proof}{\textit{\textbf {Proof:}}}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    bookmarks=true
    }

\title{Probability}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\maketitle

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introductory Material}
\section{Useful Results}

\begin{theo}[\textbf{Multinomial Theorem}]
Let \(m\ge 2\), then
\[\left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_m \right)^n=\sum_{\substack{ 0 \le k_1,k_2,\dotsc,k_m\le n\\ k_1+k_2+\dotsb+k_m=n}}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\dotsm k_m!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\dotsm x_m^{k_m} \]
\end{theo}
\begin{proof}
We will proceed by induction.
\\
\\
\underline{Base case}: \(m=2\)\\
The left side of the equation yields:
\[\left(x_1+x_2 \right)^n\]
\underline{Inductive Step}: Need to show that the formula works for \(m=\ell+1\)
\\
\\
Thus, the left side of the equation yields:
\begin{align*}
\left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell}+x_{\ell+1} \right)^n & = \left( \left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell} \right)+x_{\ell+1} \right)^n\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x_{\ell+1}^r \left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell} \right)^{n-r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x_{\ell+1}^r \left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell} \right)^{n-r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x_{\ell+1}^r \left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell} \right)^{n-r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x_{\ell+1}^r \left(x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{\ell} \right)^{n-r}  \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\begin{theo}[\textbf{Vandermonde's Identity}]
Let \(m,n,r\) be positive integers, then
\[\sum_{i=0}^r{m\choose i}{n \choose r-j}={m+n \choose r}\]
\end{theo}
\begin{proof}
Now, using the binomial theorem, we observe:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^{m+n}{m+n \choose r}x^r 
&= \left(1+x \right)^{m+n} \\
&=\left(1+x\right)^m\left(1+x\right)^n  \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

I have posted a link of the PDF output here: http://docdroid.net/llt4 if you need to see it quickly (with added commentary and blue, red and green arrows illustrating my spacing problems).

Comment: Where can one find `boiboites.sty`? In answer to the second question, perhaps try using only `\renewcommand{\proofname}{\textbf{Proof:}}`...

Comment: Ah sorry. I downloaded it from here: http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-en/index.php/tag/Download

I did modify it very slightly to make the boxed theorems rectangular and blue all-around though. I don't think the issue is with those cosmetic changes. 

I tried your line for the proof. The squares are back, but "Proof" is still in the default un-bold, italics style. It didn't seem to have done anything for some reason?

Comment: `\\ \\ ` I could have guessed they were there from the question title alone. You should remove all `\\ ` that are not in tabular or math alignments.

Comment: Naturally the qed symbol goes if you redefine proof not to add it (and to remove all the correct spacing normally added by proof environments) in fact you have omitted  the argument to `\renewenvironment` that specifies the end code so it picked up the blank line in your file as the definition of `\end{proof}`

Comment: not relevant to the question as asked, but you could simplify your `\usepackage` list by combining `mathtools` and `amsmath` (which is loaded by the former) and similarly for `amssymb` and `amsfonts`.  i haven't looked into `boiboites`, but the way that `amsthm` defines and uses `\proofname`, it shouldn't have any adverse side effects if you tried `\renewcommand{\proofname}{{\normalfont\bfseries Proof}}`

Comment: @user84226: The difference in the spacing before a display equation is due to the lengths `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip`. The former is inserted if there may be a horizontal overlap between the display and the text preceding it. The latter is inserted when that overlap might not happen; it's usually smaller so that you're not taking up unnecessary whitespace. By default they're defined to have lengths `\abovedisplayskip=12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 3pt`, which could be huge in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tips above. I really appreciate all of your help. 

However, I'm not too sure why the above solutions for my QED part weren't working. After a lot of endless searching, I finally came across this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8089/changing-style-of-proof
and Matt Fayers's answer worked exactly the way I needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compile your document without boiboites.sty, but I think your "issue" is due to the `book` `documetclass`. `Book` uses the `\flushbottom` command to stretch and compress content wherever allowed in order to make all the pages end exactly at the bottom margin to make all content justified on all sides, not just the left and right.

Adding `\raggedbottom` to your document just after `\begin{document}` may solve your problem, but personally I believe `\flushbottom` looks better for *printed* material.

On the last page, I believe the blue gap you highlighted is due to the height of the equation above; if LaTeX used a smaller gap there then characters on the left side of the equation would run into the equation above. It only looks slightly "off" to you because you don't have a left side to the equation.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working quite well in my document.