# How to define new environment, using proof-environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I'm using the package amsthm and I like to define my own proof environment, where the title *proof* is replaced by *Beweis*.

So far, I tried

`\newenvironment{bew}{\begin{proof}[\textsc{\textbf{Beweis:}}]}{\end{proof}}`

and this works fine. But now I like to improve the environment so that the argument should stay between *Beweis* and :

For example

```
 \begin{bew}[von Theorem 2.1]
     Nice proof.
 \end{bew}
```

should look like

> **Beweis von Theorem 2.1:** Nice proof.

Comment: The text "Proof" is provided by `\proofname`, so all you need to do is `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Beweis}`.  You should be able to change the font too, if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is just changing the period with a colon. Unfortunately, `amsmath` hardwires the period, so we need to patch `\proof` in order to remove the dependency.

The name will switch to “Beweis” as soon as you load `babel` with an option for German, usually `ngerman` if you adhere to the “neue Rechtschreibung”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% we need to substitute . with a generic command
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{\proofpunctuation}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofpunctuation}{:} % change to your liking

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The input

```
\begin{proof}[Beweis von Satz 1]
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}
```

will produce the expected result.

If you prefer boldface, another patch is in order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% we need to substitute . with a generic command
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{\proofpunctuation}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofpunctuation}{:}
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Beweis von Satz 1]
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your font supports boldface small caps (few fonts do), you can say

```
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\scshape\bfseries}
```

A syntax such as `\begin{proof}[von Satz 1]` to automatically supply “Beweis” could be done too, but I'd not do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% we need to substitute . with a generic command
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{.}{\proofpunctuation}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{#1}{\proofname\ifx\proofname#1\else #1\fi}{}{}

\newcommand{\proofpunctuation}{:}
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[von Satz 1]
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

You can also do with a new environment, which avoids patching.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bew}{o}
 {\proof[\normalfont\bfseries\proofname\IfValueT{#1}{ #1}:]}
 {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{bew}
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{bew}

\begin{bew}[von Satz 1]
Das ist ein schöner Beweis.
\end{bew}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like your last example, because in that case I don't have to change all my enviroments :-) But \begin{bew}[von Satz 1] give __Beweis von Satz 1:.__ Somehow I get a point after the doublepoint.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt I can only guess you tampered with space factor codes. This will happen if you set (or a package/class you load does) ``\sfcode`:=1000``. But in that case you would get the period also without the optional argument.

Comment: Not sure, because a use copied a lot of code. But in that case I will use the first version. That works well. I thank you!